# Is it possible to install a platform signed app to user space?

Tags: android, apk, android-build

I've come across a strange issue in a custom Android build recently? I've had a working ROM for months, and using this ROM I've been able to install platform signed apks to user space (/data/app). Recently, after rebuilding the ROM, I've been unable to install those same apks. Any attempt to install a platform signed app (whether it's via adb install, or pm install) yields the following message:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION]
```

After digging through the Android source, I found the following relevant code block:

```
if ((compareSignatures(pkg.mSignatures, s1) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH)) {
   Slog.w(TAG, "Cannot install platform packages to user storage");
   mLastScanError = PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION;
   return null;
}
```

Based on my reading, it seems that installing system applications in user space should never have been allowed. Was the initial case where installing system applications in user space an anomaly? Is it possible to install platform signed applications in user space and if so, how does one do it?

Comment: Short answer is no! platform signed apps are part of the ROM, and thus, if needing a platform signed app in userspace requires the signature keys **that was generated at build time of when the ROM was baked**

Comment: So I have access to the keys generated at build time, and I am using those keys. It was working for months, and recently stopped working, which is what has confused me. (I wish I could give you a clear idea of what's changed, but to the best of my knowledge, nothing has changed). If I re-sign the app with the keys generated during the latest build, should I be able to install the platform-cert-signed app to user space?

Comment: Yes, in the context of my previous comment - that applies only to factory ROMs, but rolling your own ROM, it *should* work nonetheless :) Sorry if I confused you there... :)

Comment: This is the thing I just don't get. It worked for months. And now it doesn't work anymore. But the code block I pasted above suggests that it should never work. Thanks for the clarification though, it helps to know that having had it previously working was not an anomaly.

Comment: perhaps try doing a clean build of the ROM, a `make clobber` within the source, something went awry there... :\

Comment: Added my discoveries on this problem in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation described above occurred because we have a shared Android build machine (shared within the company). A co-worker switched a Git branch without informing me, and thus we were left with old code in our build space. Switching it back to the correct branch solved the problem. To answer the above question more explicitly, it appears that unless you comment out the following code-block, installing platform signed applications in user space is not possible.

(The class file is */frameworks/base/services/src/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java*);

```
    if (!pkg.applicationInfo.sourceDir.startsWith(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath()) &&
            !pkg.applicationInfo.sourceDir.startsWith("/vendor")) {
        Object obj = mSettings.getUserIdLPr(1000);
        Signature[] s1 = null;
        if (obj instanceof SharedUserSetting) {
            s1 = ((SharedUserSetting)obj).signatures.mSignatures;
        }
        if ((compareSignatures(pkg.mSignatures, s1) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH)) {
            Slog.w(TAG, "Cannot install platform packages to user storage");
            mLastScanError = PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION;
            return null;
        }
    }
```